# When I run this command to deploy the solana contract this error is reported

Tags: solana, solana-program-library

So when I run this

`ts-node C:\Users\ras zebi\Desktop\solana boobs\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k C:\Users\ras zebi\Desktop\solana boobs\keypair\my-keypair.json -cp C:\Users\ras zebi\Desktop\solana boobs\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\example-candy-machine-upload-config.json C:\Users\ras zebi\Desktop\solana boobs\metaplex-master\my assets`

I get this

```
Error: Cannot find module './ras'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (C:\Users\ras zebi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:496:16)   
    at getProjectSearchDir (C:\Users\ras zebi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:466:40)       
    at phase3 (C:\Users\ras zebi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:268:27)
    at bootstrap (C:\Users\ras zebi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:44:30)
    at main (C:\Users\ras zebi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:32:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ras zebi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:526:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript' ]
```

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: I assume all of your Windows paths in your command need to be quoted, because you have an ill-advisable space in your user folder (`C:\Users\ras zebi`).

Comment: Check also your `packages.json` for this project - are there any dependencies you need to install with Yarn or NPM?